# Probability Struggle/Stick Problem

Tags: probability

I am taking a probability class and I am struggling with this problem:

Take a stick of unit length and break it into two pieces, choosing the break point at random. Now break the longer of two pieces at a random point. What is the probability that the three pieces can be used to form a triangle?

I found this which is the answer:
integral from 0 to 0.5 of (x/(1 - x))dx/(0.5-0)

Why do we divide it by 0.5-0?

Comment: Have you tried coming up with the solution yourself? If so, what did you try?

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I got everything except the dividing by 0.5 part.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could outline your solution so forum browsers can actually see where you might have made an error.

Comment: The solution is correct but I don't know where 0.5 comes from.

Answer (score 1):

If your first cut is at position $x$ where $x < 0.5$, then the longer stick has length $1-x$. When cutting the longer stick, you need to ensure that both resulting pieces are longer than $0.5 - x$ (else, the sum of two sides will be smaller than the third side). This leaves a region of length $(1-x) - 2(0.5-x) = x$ where you can make the second cut on the longer stick.

So, given $x < 0.5$, the conditional probability that the second cut is valid is $\frac{x}{1-x}$. There are two ways of finishing the problem.

- If you consider the cases $x < 0.5$ and $x > 0.5$ separately, you get $$\int_0^{0.5} \frac{x}{1-x} \, dx  + \int_{0.5}^1 \frac{1-x}{x} \, dx = 2 \int_0^{0.5} \frac{x}{1-x} \, dx.$$ (The $\frac{1-x}{x}$ comes from repeating the above argument regarding the second cut in the case $x>0.5$.)
- If you recognize that the cases $x < 0.5$ and $x > 0.5$ are symmetric, so you simply consider always cutting at a point $x$ chosen uniformly over $[0, 0.5]$, then the PDF of this new uniform random variable has value $\frac{1}{0.5-0} = 2$ on $[0, 0.5]$, so you have $\int_0^{0.5} \frac{x/(1-x)}{0.5-0} \, dx$.

By the way, next time if you are referring to a certain argument/discussion, just [link](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/70602.html) to it. It will save us a lot of trouble guessing the context of the argument.